# Where to store views for theme?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, themes, yii

By default in Yii framework, views are stored inside theme's folder.

There are two options:
1. To store view inside module's or widget's folder.
2. To store view inside theme's folder.

Where better to store the views and why?

Answer (score 0):

IMO this depends on the views. If you have lots of logic in them, I'd ship with the module / widget, but if it's mainly markup it makes more sense to place it inside the theme folder. I think Yii suggests the latter as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on whether you want to reuse the views of the modules and widgets in other applications. If so then it would be wise to store the views within the module/widgets folder so it's 1 package.

In my setup I have a 'common' map that stores all the logic of the modules/widgets/extensions but not the views. I reuse the logic of the widgets/modules in my applications but the views are slightly different per application (for example: a top 10 posters widget in a sidebar or something that takes data and shows it in the footer). This gives great flexibility to your applications imho.